# Windows server 2008 r2 unable to view folder as administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

I have a windows server 2008 r2 install that I inherited and am in the process of prepping for rebuild. Of all the folders of data I had to move to our new machine, there is 1 folder that I, as admin, cannot access due to lack of permissions. icacl foldername /reset failed. Going to the advanced tab under security and trying to take ownership failed. Moreover, I cannot see who is the owner for this folder. Can anyone recommend a way I can access this folder or at least view who the owner is? (again, on the security tab I get the message that I do not have permission to view the owner or permissions on the folder).

I should add, I only saw the contents of the folder during a run of robocopy, as errors in its log.

Comment: I would run check disk.  Not being able to tak permissions occasionally indicates filesystem corruption.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you! I had to run this a few times in a row to get progressively more access to the files until I could copy all the files off. Oddly enough, SMART is not failing on that specific drive (but it is on other drives in the system, and the disks ARE NOT IN A RAID).